# resizing images not working with me in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to resize image in codeigniter in one function

i called Image_lib and upload libraries on my controller

the images folder gets read/write .

That is my controller.

```
public function update(){

    $config['upload_path']="./images/";
    $config['allowed_types']='jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name']=TRUE;
    $config['max_size']='1024';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);


    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $this->load->view('settings_v',array(
        'userdata'=>$this->user->userdata(),
        'c_data'=>$this->Settings_m->index(),
        'error'=>$this->upload->display_errors(),
        ));
    } else{
        $image=$this->Settings_m->image(); // get current image to remove it 
        if(!empty($image)){
            $path='images/'.$image;
            unlink($path);
        }
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = '.images/'.$filename;
        $config['new_image'] = '.images/'.$filename;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 30;
        $config['height'] = 30;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $file_data=$this->upload->data();
        $filename=$file_data['file_name'];
        $this->Settings_m->update($filename);
        //redirect('Settings','refresh');
    }

}
```

Thanks ,

Comment: Change '.images/ to './images/' also you never defined `$filename`  before using it in image lib config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change '.images/ to './images/' also you never defined `$filename` before using it in image lib config.

```
    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
    $filename = $file_data['file_name'];
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './images/' . $filename;
    $config['new_image'] = './images/' . $filename;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 30;
    $config['height'] = 30;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->Settings_m->update($filename);
    //redirect('Settings','refresh');
```

Also if you just want to resize the source image and not have a separate resized image you should remove `$config['new_image']` and `$config['create_thumb']` as per the docs. Otherwise just use `create_thumb` or `new_image` (with a different path/filename than the original) but not both.

> Notes regarding this preference:
>
> If neither of the two preferences listed above (create_thumb, and
>   new_image) are used, the resizing method will instead target the
>   original image for processing.